# Unable to filter all observations using a column value with dtype object in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to filter out observations based on a specific column with dtype object.

When I run value_counts() on the series it gives me a very high number.

```
df['object'].value_counts()
```

Output:

```
Obj1    20433
Obj2    14237
Obj3    11101
```

But when I am trying to filter the observations it is returning a lesser number of observations

```
df.loc[df['object']=='Obj1'].shape
```

Output:

```
(6, 12)
```

I am unable to understand why there is a disparity in results.
Thanks

Comment: if you are doing string equality check why not `df['object'].astype(str) == 'Obj1'`

Comment: @RaghavaDhanya using `astype('str')` did the job, thanks

Comment: @jezrael `df['object'].str.strip().value_counts()` returned the same result

Comment: @MradulVerma - Check what do you have in `df.object.unique()` ? And if you see multiple Obj1, then you may need to `strip` all the values in `object` column